# python canvas.coord() accumulate memory

Tags: python, user-interface, memory-leaks, tkinter

I've made a simple analog clock with tkinter to study python GUIing. Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *
from datetime import datetime
import threading
from math import cos, sin, pi

root = Tk()
root.geometry('400x400')
pause = True

def sec_to_coord(second):
    x = cos((second - 15) * pi / 30)
    y = sin((-second - 15) * pi / 30)
    return x,y

def update():
    global pause
    if pause: return
    threading.Timer(1, update).start()
    now = datetime.now()
    x,y = sec_to_coord(now.second)
    canv.coords(line, 200, 200, x * 100 + 200, y * 100 + 200) # drains RAM
    x,y = sec_to_coord(now.minute + now.second / 60)
    canv.coords(minhand, 200, 200, x * 90 + 200, y * 90 + 200) # drains RAM
    x,y = sec_to_coord(now.hour * 5 + now.minute / 12)
    canv.coords(hourhand, 200, 200, x * 50 + 200, y * 50 + 200) # drains RAM
    print(':'.join([str(now.hour), str(now.minute), str(now.second)]))

def start():
    global pause
    if not pause: return
    pause = False
    print('pause =', pause)
    update()

def halt():
    global pause
    if not pause: 
        pause = True
        print('pause =', pause)

def on_closing():
    halt()
    print('BUY-BUY!')
    root.destroy()

canv = Canvas(root, width=400, height=400)
canv.pack()
line = canv.create_line(200, 200, 200, 100)
minhand = canv.create_line(200, 200, 200, 110, width = 3)
hourhand = canv.create_line(200, 200, 200, 150, width= 7)
ticks = []
for i in range(60):
    x,y = sec_to_coord(i)
    if i % 5 == 0:
        ticks.append(canv.create_line(x*90+200, y*90+200, \
            x*100+200, y*100+200, width=3))
    else:
        ticks.append(canv.create_line(x*95+200, y*95+200, \
            x*100+200, y*100+200, width=3))

root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', on_closing)
start()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem is: while ticking, the clock accumulates RAM. By commenting parts of the code I've found that `canv.coord()` function in `def update():` is responsible.
Please, can somebody tell me what is wrong with the code?

Comment: tkinter isn't thread safe. There are simple techniques for doing animation in tkinter that don't require threads.

Comment: @BryanOakley: whether or not tkinter is (as opposed to intended to be) 'thread safe' seems to depend of the definition of the term and the Python version.  See https://bugs.python.org/issue11077 and Martin's comments, as well as https://bugs.python.org/issue16823. where I report that threaded tkinter code failing in 2.7 works in 3.5.

Comment: Use `root.after(1000, update)` instead of the Timer call.  It does more or less the same thing using the tk loop.  Look at other answers using `root.after` for animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you, Terry!!! That solved the problem! I had to change just one line as you suggested `root.after(1000, update)` instead of `threading.Timer(1, update).start()` and RAM accumulation disappeared!